# How can I extract interval time between words in mp3 (audio) file by MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, audio-processing

I am trying to find interval time between words in several mp3 (audio file)
Before going further, let me explain about my audio files as below:

I asked my subjects to generate as many animal names as possible in 60 seconds. And I recorded their speech. 
Therefore, all of mp3 files are sequences of animal names. (words, not sentence continuously)

First, I read one of the files and make a graph by just typing:

```
plot(data);
```

The graph is as below:
[image]

I think some local maximums are candidates of animal naming. However, I cannot figure out and get the (possibly exact) interval time between animal names. 
Just peak to peak is okay? or any other alternatives for calculating the intervals between words? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Peak to peak is very coarse etimation for the silence segments between the vocals segments. The method of threshold that @vsoch suggested also not allways suitable, because the vocal segments contains also low, and zero values.

The conventional method to extract the silence segments is comparing energies over different segments. You need to divide the signal to segments of around 30 ms (the exact number of samples depends on the sample rate). You also better do it with overlap of about 10 ms between segments.

For each segment evaluate the energy. this can be done by `sum(segment.^2)` (psaudocode...). Then plot the energies you've got, to see and choose the threshold that will separate between vocal and silence segments.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`findpeaks`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html)

```
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(data)
```

You could find the local maxes that way, go left and right until it drops to a certain threshold or by a certain percentage (since the peaks have some girth), and then order them, and calculate the distances between as a subtraction between values.